# Converting URL to HTTPS via Javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to convert current url to https version with javascript. How can i done this ?

Ex: http://www.example.com --> https://www.example.com

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
window.location = window.location.href.replace(/^http:/, 'https:');
```

Comment: Good one! You probably also want to check whether it is `http:` before: `if (window.location.protocol == 'http:') {}`

Answer (score 4):

If you know that your http URL starts with "http://", then it is as simple as:

```
var httpsUrl = "https" + httpUrl.substring(4);
```